# Jquery not submitting my form

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I want to submit my form using JQuery but I don't know why it won't work for me. here's the code:

```
$("#search_result_fake_div2").live("click", function () {
        $("#search_result_present_list2").show("fast");
        $('body').one('click',function() {
            $("#search_result_present_list2").hide();
              });
             event.stopPropagation();

    });

 $(".search_result_list_item2").live("click", function () {
            $("#search_result_fake2").val($(this).html());
            $("#getattendees").submit();
            $("#search_result_present_list2").hide();
        });
```

and my HTML code:

```
<div>
    <div id="search_result_fake_container">
    <div id="search_result_fake_div2"></div>

    <form method="GET" id="getattendees">
    <input type="text" id="search_result_fake2" value="<?php if(!empty($city)){echo $city;} else{echo "Select Event";}?>" name="event_name">
    </form>

    </div>

    <div id="search_result_present_list2">

        <?php foreach ($events as $events1): ?>
        <div class="search_result_list_item2" id="search_result_item_12" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $events1['event_name']; ?></div>
        <?php endforeach ?>

    </div>
    </div>
```

This is a drop down menu using div which came from my other question. One thing that I want to happen is for the form to submit once I've clicked a content from the drop down selection. I tried using `onchange="javascript: document.getattendees.submit();"` on my input box but nothing happens so I'm thinking of using jQuery instead but still the problem persists. I'm just a newbie on the jQuery and in fact I'm not that well versed on this one.

Comment: jquery .live function was deprecated.

Comment: Is your form element missing the action attribute?

Comment: .live() should be .on() to expound on what sujathan said, and to brains911 's point, where does this form submit to? thin air? ;)

Comment: I see, sorry Im not that familiar with the syntax. will try your suggestions. :)

Comment: Hi VIDesignz, tried your suggestions and its working! thanks! Feel free to add your comments to answer so I can select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
  $('form#getattendees').trigger('submit');
```